ID TV show, three kids that catch monsters or creatures
Ok, so I've been looking for this show since forever. My friends swear it doesn't exist. The show was about these 3 kids that caught monsters or creatures. There was a leader who was a redhead with glasses, and I think she had a coat where she had things and weapons, kind of like Inspector Gadget. And then there was a boy, I think he was blond and blue eyed, he had the ability to transform into any abject he wanted. Finally, there was the second girl, who was black and had curly hair and I think she wore a pink shirt. She also had some sort of psychic powers. The animation was sort of stop motion and it had a hint of Tim Burton style. Somebody please tell me if I'm making it up because I swear I've been looking for this show for 5 years now. 

Welcome to the community. Did you say this is animated? Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the genre, language, country and year of production, plot locale, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

When did you first see the show? That would help narrow it down. (For instance, if you think you first saw an episode in the year 2000, we could disregard anything that's only been produced in the 21st Century.)


I believe the show your looking for is called phantom investigators. I found someone looking for a show that sounded similar to the show you're mentioning.
